# Puppet file resource not resolving the source attribute

Tags: puppet, centos7

I have started to play with puppet 5 and for some reason the `source` attribute in the puppet `file` resource is not working. I have a simple manifest file in my puppet server which is as follows:

```
file {'/tmp/motd':
  source => '/tmp/motd',
}
```

On the agent, I issue:

```
puppet agent -t
```

which errors out as:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/motd]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) file:/tmp/motd
```

The file `motd` exists on the puppet server in `/tmp/` directory

Any idea what might be going on here?

If I replace `source` attribute with `content => 'Testing 1 2 3'`, the `puppet agent -t` runs successfully creating a catalogue and I see the file `motd` on the client with the content `Testing 1 2 3`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the docs [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/types/file.html#file-attribute-source%08), the `source` attribute refers to a local file, i.e. local on the Puppet Agent node.

If you wish to source the file from the Puppet Server, it would be best to place the file content in the module's files directory as explained [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/modules_fundamentals.html#files-in-modules%08).